# Kafka JDBC Sink - Failed to deserialize data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Following is the configuration for topic `topic_62`

`Type: Avro Compatibility mode: Backward Used by topics`

`Schema`

```
  {
  "type": "record",
  "name": "myrecord",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "record_id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "success",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "response",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "stage",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
}
```

** JDBC SINK Connector **

```
{
  "name": "integration-service-mysql-connector",
  "config": {
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "mode.incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "mode.timestamp.column.name": "timestamp",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "name": "integration-service-mysql-connector",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "transforms": "",
    "errors.retry.timeout": "2",
    "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "5000",
    "errors.tolerance": "none",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "topics": "topic_62",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/integration",
    "connection.user": "root",
    "connection.password": "*****",
    "dialect.name": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
    "connection.attempts": "5",
    "connection.backoff.ms": "3000",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "batch.size": "1",
    "delete.enabled": "false",
    "table.name.format": "integration.txn_record_audit",
    "pk.mode": "none",
    "db.timezone": "Asia/Kolkata",
    "auto.create": "false",
    "auto.evolve": "false",
    "quote.sql.identifiers": "always",
    "max.retries": "5",
    "retry.backoff.ms": "1000",
    "trim.sensitive.log": "false"
  }
}
```

** Database Schema **

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default              | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL                 | auto_increment |
| record_id | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL                 |                |
| success   | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | 0                    |                |
| response  | text        | YES  |     | NULL                 |                |
| stage     | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL                 |                |
| timestamp | datetime(3) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3) |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+----------------------+----------------+
```

** Tried **

1. Ran Avro conole produces

```
kafka-avro-console-producer 
--broker-list localhost:9092 \ 
--topic  topic_62 \
--property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"record_id","type":"int"},{"name":"success", "type": "int"}, {"name":"response", "type": ["null", "string"]}, {"name":"stage","type": "string"}]}'
```

> > `{"record_id" : 1,"success" : 12,"response" : null,"stage" : "Some"}`

Got NO ERROR ( means the json is successfully consumed

** Exception **

Keep getting this error

```
[2024-01-30 10:54:57,167] ERROR [integration-service-mysql-connector|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=integration-service-mysql-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:237)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:244)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:534)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:509)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:345)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:243)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:212)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:229)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:284)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Failed to deserialize data for topic topic_62 to Avro: 
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$5(WorkerSinkTask.java:534)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:224)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Unknown magic byte!
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.getByteBuffer(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDe.java:600)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer$DeserializationContext.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:386)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.deserializeWithSchemaAndVersion(AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer.java:261)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Deserializer.deserialize(AvroConverter.java:199)
    at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:126)
    ... 17 more
```

How to resolve this issue of De serialization ?

It should have successfully serialized

Next battle was to save into the mysql database

Comment: after adding dead letter queue - i was able to get to mysql part